# I would like to make a circle more smooth

Tags: modeling

I got the data with fbx, but I want to make it a smoother circle because it is angular.

I tried subvidide, but it didn't become a smooth circle, only the splits for each surface increased.

Is there no choice but to recreate it from scratch?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you enable the "looptools"-addon

[image]

you can just select your circle, subdivide it and then search with F3 for looptools -> circle.

[image]

Comment: omg.,..! Finally I did! I was trying to do it 2 hours.;. lol  Thank you so much !!

Comment: very gladly!!!!